# Fetching API data with active login

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm using backend functions on my website to gather data from a separate website.

I can access the data easily with something like...

```
fetch( DataURL, {"method": "get"} )
            .then( httpResponse => httpResponse.json() )
            .then( json => { console.log(json); } )
```

However, there is additional data fields in the json data that aren't visible unless you are logged in.

I'm trying to use a POST fetch to complete the login form, and then send the GET to retrieve the API data afterwards.  Have been unsuccessful so far.

```
fetch( LoginURL, {
        "method": "post",
        "body": "Username=myusername&Password=mypassword",
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        })
    .then( fetch( DataURL, {"method": "get"} )
            .then( httpResponse => httpResponse.json() )
            .then( json => { console.log(json); })
    })
```

I'm basing the body data on what I see in the form in their source code.  Not completely sure if I'm doing that right.

This is a phpBB style website that needs to be logged into.

```
<form action="./ucp.php?mode=login" method="post" id="navloginform" name="loginform">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" size="10" class="form-control" title="Username"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" size="10" class="form-control" title="Password"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="autologin-navbar"><input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="autologin-navbar" tabindex="4" /> Remember me</label>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="./ucp.php?mode=login" />
<button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login</button>
</form>
```

I'm very clearly doing something wrong.

I think my main issues I'm struggling with are:

1. Is my guess at how to use their form data correct?
2. How do I verify the login even worked to begin with?
3. Do I need to do something special to maintain the login before sending a second fetch?

Comment: What's the purpose of retrieving html content on the backend server?

Comment: @Hiro It's a daily database sync/update.

Comment: Normally when you need protected data from a different backend service (a 3rd party service), you typically need a protected route to fetch data from. These end points typically require some kind of authentication token. Which you either get by login in each time or a general token generated from their developer panel.

Comment: From what i see, you are mimicking a user login & trying to access the protected data. Which does not work in the REST API world are there are no session/cookies associated here. So when you request the second endpoint url you get only the public data not the private.

Comment: @JibinBose They don't have any special API keys for accessing under the login that I'm aware of.  If I manually login with a browser and go to the same data page, I see the protected data.  So, yes, I'm trying to mimic that process.  Should I be trying to use cookies to maintain the login?

Comment: The third party application that you are trying to access data from mostly would be using a session based auth logic to retrieve data from the server. For example, this may include session data stored as cookies in the front end & related data stored in application server sessions. You will need to decipher how their auth logic works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to share how I got mine working, though may be different for other cases.

--

Go to the website you're trying to login to, and open up your browser development tools.

Select the 'Network' tab, and login.

Find the network entry from your login, and go to the 'Headers' tab.  Near the bottom of the entry will show which headers were used.  Not all of these are critical.  Something like below:

[image: Headers]

When using your fetch call, create the same headers as needed in the body.

```
const LoginURL = 'www.ExampleWebpageLogin.com./ucp.php?mode=login';

let form = new FormData();

form.append('username', 'MyUsername');
form.append('password', 'MyPassword');
form.append('login', 'Login');

var headers = { 'method': 'post',
                'body': form,
                'credentials': 'include'}

await fetch( LoginURL, headers)
    .then( loginResponse => {
        console.log(loginResponse);
    })
```

In my case, the loginResponse included 2 critical cookies.

1. user_id - This cookie value remained =1 when not logged in, and was set to my user id once successful.
2. sid - Most likely session ID, which they use to preserve login session.

For both the login post and future GET requests, 'credentials' are required.